# Asterisk - DAY & NIGHT

Tags: asterisk

I slowly desperate yet. I simply do not understand the principle of include in extensions.conf.

i hahe this code in my extensions.conf:

```
[GLOBAL]
include => technik|15:00-17:00|mon-sa|*|*
include => nachtschaltung


[technik]
include => technik|15:00-17:00|mon-sa|*|*
include => night
exten = 620,1, Answer()
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n, Playback(hello-world)
same = n, Hangup()


[night]
exten = n,1, Answer()
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n, Playback(system-crashed)
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n, Playback(system-crashed)
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n, Playback(system-crashed)
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n, Hangup()
```

How can I get now that after a certain time, another call plan (night) is selected? 
Do I need to change something in a different file? For example, at the sip.conf?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Include used for include other context inside this one.

GLOBAL section include NOT work.

There are plenty of books which describe asterisk dialplan step-by-step. For example "Asterisk the future of telephony".